# How to fix Dell Latitude E6410 Windows 10 new install boots to blank screen with mouse cursor

Tags: boot, laptop, windows-10, dell-latitude

Problem: New install of Windows 10 on Dell Latitude E6410 boots to a blank screen with only a mouse cursor. Pressing key combo's like fn-f8 will revel a side panel saying that you cannot switch to another screen as some driver failed to start. Thus the display is somewhat responsive.

Similar to: [Dell Latitude E6410 blank screen](https://superuser.com/questions/530054/dell-latitude-e6410-blank-screen) and [PC Boots to black screen with mouse cursor](https://superuser.com/questions/457635/pc-boots-to-black-screen-with-mouse-cursor)

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was Shift+F10 after boot to the blank screen with only a cursor. I actually pressed Shift+F10 and then Shift+Ctrl+F10 but research has shown that likely it was the Shift+F10 key combo that moved me froward in the install. I have one more of these laptop to upgrade but that wont happen for a few weeks. I'll report back after upgrading the next one.

Other resources I used while researching this issue:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-10-upgrade-on-my-dell-latitude-e6410-does/6ef4fc65-3086-4260-a3e5-2f18e1f3f4c2?auth=1

http://www.pcworld.com/article/2984712/windows/how-to-enter-windows-10s-safe-mode.html

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396